# Is it possible to open an SQLite database inside pgadmin?

Tags: pgadmin

I was trying to find a way of opening SQLite databases inside pgadmin and I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049328/how-to-open-sqlite-db-in-postgresql) where one solution points to importing the SQLite database inside PostgreSQL, and the other solution tells us to use PostgreSQL Wrappers. I'd like to open an SQLite database inside pgadmin without importing it to my PostgreSQL database.

I know that I can run queries on other databases with a PostgreSQL database like in [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408036/173457), where PostgreSQL is used for running a query on a SpatiaLite database (an SQLite extension). However, my goal is to use pgadmin to run queries on an SQLite database, without using any command-line tools or programming languages to achieve that. Is it possible? Can I manage my SQLite databases inside the pgadmin interface?

Comment: *the other solution tells us to use PostgreSQL Wrappers* - apply this solution.

Comment: @Akina Actually that's not as simple as it looks like... I've implemented the solution of my second link already (that question is also mine). But my issue is not about running a PostgreSQL query on an SQLite database. In my view, that's the purpose of Wrappers. What I wanted to do is different though, I wanted to use pgadmin to manage SQLite databases, so implementing the Wrappers doesn't solve my issue. Honestly, I think the only solution is stop using pgadmin and going for a different DB management tool. I made this question to be sure if I wasn't missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I manage my SQLite databases inside the pgadmin interface?

**No.**
pgAdmin is meant for Postgres, not for SQLite. The two are completely incompatible on that level of access.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you feel the need to do this?

DBMSs and their management tools are *wildly* different from one another.

- Consider the controls that you use to drive your car.
  Could you use these same controls to "drive" a commercial airliner?
- Consider the controls in the cockpit of a commercial airliner.
  Could you use these same controls to drive your car?

OK, there *is* a degree of *commonality* between the two ...

- things to make the vehicle go faster or slower
- things to make the vehicle change direction
- things that open and close [some of] the doors

... but there are *loads* of controls that are *specific* to the vehicle itself.

Of, you *might* be able to squeeze that airliner into a parking spot at your local Walmart, but you're probably going to cause an *awful* lot of trouble in doing so, for yourself and for everyone else!

Comment: Thanks for the analogy... I'll take that as a "no, it's not possible and it's not a good idea" :). Actually, I know there are other software that could access multiple databases instead of pgadmin. My insistence on trying to do it with pgadmin is because in my context I work in a place where way too many people already use pgadmin, so instead of trying to make everyone use a different software I wanted to solve the SQLite problem in the same software. In your analogy, it's like saying "There are a lot of car drivers available, but for doing what's necessary we need a plane".